# Draw polygon with specific dimensions

Tags: polygon-creation, alignment, rectangle, center

I'm a beginner with QGIS, and I'm trying to draw a polygon that is 10m x 10m with 90 degree angles placed along a line, and centred around a point on that line.

I don't know what projection to use (I'm in Australia and using GDA94 Zone 56), or even if that affects anything (it does when I tried to buffer the point by 10m and it shows in degrees).

How do I:

1. Draw a polygon with specific dimensions and corner angles?
2. Rotate it so it runs parallel with a line and actually goes over the top of it?
3. Centre the polygon on a specific point of that line?

I've searched everything I can think of but can't seem to get it working for me.